# monit "check program" with email?

Tags: monit

I have this in a monit script (lines 11-13):

```
check program foo with
    path "/usr/local/bin/foo.sh" with timeout 300 seconds
       if status != 0 then alert dan@example.com
```

monit reload says:

```
/etc/monit/conf.d/example:13: Error: syntax error 'dan@example.com'
```

None of the [examples](http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#program_status_testing) show an email with the alert, but I need one. Why can I not give one here?

I'm using Monit 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

Uncomment/Add these lines in your monit config file:

```
set mailserver localhost
set alert me@mycompany.com
```

Then do something like the following. Notice that there is nothing after "alert".

```
check program list-files with path "/bin/ls -lrt /tmp/"
     if status != 0 then alert
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation at http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#setting_a_local_alert_statement
it has the following example

```
check process mybar with pidfile /var/run/mybar.pid
  alert foo@bar only on { timeout }
```

Comment: I saw that example, but how does it relate to this?  That example says "each service can have its own recipient list."  How is this statement a service?  And it also shows that a legal alert in that context has only an email address, no "only on { timeout }".

Answer (score 0):

Look specifically at: https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#Setting-an-alert-recipient (new link), the way I read this, for a local alert (if you want an additional email for just this alert), you would add it to the end of the current section.

From the link above:

## Local alert example:

```
   check host myhost with address 1.2.3.4  
     if failed port 3306 protocol mysql then alert  
     if failed port 80 protocol http then alert  
     alert foo@baz # Local service alert
```

You will note, the failed check and alert notification are on the second and third lines, then a local email address is added to the final line.